# Wordpress adding onclick action to an <a> tag

Tags: php, wordpress

I have no idea of how can I do this, I am searching for few days now to find out how to add an onClick action to 2 `<a>` tags in a website.

I have to do this for someone who asked me. He wants to check how many times the `<a>` tags were clicked. Some kind of traffic tracking.

I searching through the php files and I could not find an id which is the container where the a tag is.

Any ideas how can I add the following code to the onClick event?

```
onClick="_gaq.push([ '_trackEvent', 'Downloads', 'Downloads Android'])"
```

This is what I have in my wordpress related to those 2 links:

```
[vc_row_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/2"][vc_single_image image="2051" alignment="center" border_color="grey" img_link_target="_blank" img_size="337x100" img_link="https://itunes.apple.com/ro/app/printie/id907472105?mt=8"][/vc_column_inner]

[vc_column_inner width="1/2"][vc_single_image image="2053" alignment="center" border_color="grey" img_link_target="_blank" img_link="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ro.printie.android&amp;hl=en" img_size="306x100"][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner]
```

Comment: Are you targeting all the links ? I mean, you want every links in your page to run this code ?

Comment: No, just 2 links. One for android and one for iphone links

Comment: if you cannot find those links in php files, maybe they are not hardcoded, but are in an article or a widget..? Did you search there ?

Comment: Yeah; I've got just the same setup on http://splendid-things.co.uk/getrunning/ — we have Google Analytics onclick stuff added to each of the iOS and Android app links so we can tell how many people go where. The links themselves are in the page content, so you edit them by just editing the page in WordPress; they're stored in the database, so you won't see them by searching the PHP. Why not ask your client who created/edits the original links, and how they did it? Chances are you just need access to the WordPress admin interface to change them.

Comment: @JuniusRendel I don't know wordpress very well... So I don't know where to search.

Comment: show html code what you see there

Comment: @FlorinPop Generally you'd change WordPress page content by logging in as someone with editing privileges, visiting the page you want to change, and hitting the "Edit Page" link in the menubar at the top. It's incredibly easy, but you'll need a login.

Comment: @MattGibson I have the login, and the website is one page website.

Comment: @FlorinPop If you don't see an "Edit Page" at the top when you're logged in, try visiting the admin interface directly by heading for the page "wp-admin", e.g. if the website is `http://example.com/`, try `http://example.com/wp-admin`. If you see an admin interface, then see if you see a "Pages" menu in the sidebar. If you do, click it, and see if you can find the page in the list. Editing should be a simple matter of hovering over the page name and hitting the "Edit" link. If not, you may have more luck asking on http://wordpress.stackoverflow.com—this isn't really a programming question.

Comment: @MattGibson I do see edit, and I can see FrontEnd Editor and BackEnd Editor but all I can see is : `[button color="green" size="small" target="_self" url="#Download" border="false"]DOWNLOAD[/button]` Where can I add that code here?

Comment: Ah! Okay, so what's going on is that there's a plugin or theme that creates the button-style link for you (probably some kind of Bootstrap-derived theme add-on.) The `[Button ...]` is a WordPress "shortcode" that will generate all the HTML needed for a button to come out on the front-end. If you're lucky, the shortcode designer will have supported `onclick`—try just adding `onclick="whatever"` to the attributes, then publish the page ("publish" button is usually top-right in the editing interface) and then see if your `onclick` attribute has been added to the `a` element.

Comment: @MattGibson I uploaded my question, check it out please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67458/discussion-between-florin-pop-and-matt-gibson).